# Javascript events and recursion issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am using jQuery Dialog to load other pages into a dialog on the main page.  The other pages may have anchor tags, and I am using the completed event of the load function to select all of the anchor tags in the div into which the content was loaded.  I then  wire up the anchor tags click event handler so that the content is loaded into the div which is contained on the main page.  This works, however only twice.  When you run the sample code below, Partial1 appears in the dialog.  When I click on the Partial2 link in the dialog, Partial1 is loaded into the dialog, however, this time when I click on the Partial2 link, it loads in the main page.  What am I doing wrong and/or failing to grasp?

**Home/Index:**

```
<a href="/Home/Partial1" id="help">Partial 1</a>

<div id="dialog" style="display: none">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#help").click(function () {
            adjustNestedAnchors($(this));
            $("#dialog").dialog().show();
            return false;
        });

        function adjustNestedAnchors(element) {
            $("#dialog").load($(element).attr("href"),
                function (response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status != "error") {
                        $("#dialog a").click(function () {
                                $("#dialog").load($(this).attr("href"), adjustNestedAnchors($(this)));
                                return false;
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Home/Partial1**

```
This is a sample partial view, which has a link back to <a href="/Home/Partial2">Partial2</a>.
```

**Home/Partial2**

```
This is a sample partial view, which has a link back to <a href="/Home/Partial1">Partial1</a>.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
$("#dialog").load($(this).attr("href"), adjustNestedAnchors($(this)));
```

will call `adjustNestedAnchors` on the link *before* calling `load` on the `div`, so there's nothing that adjusts the nested anchors *after* the content has been loaded.

Instead, I believe what you want is something like this:

```
<a href="/Home/Partial1" id="help">Partial 1</a>

<div id="dialog" style="display: none">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#help").click(function () {
            loadDialog(this);
            $("#dialog").dialog().show();
            return false;
        });

        // load link in dialog, and adjust its links to load inside it
        function loadDialog(link) {
            $("#dialog").load($(link).attr("href"), function (response, status, xhr) {
                $("#dialog a").click(function () {
                    loadDialog(this);
                    return false;
                });
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

(Disclaimer: not tested.)

Note that I've renamed `adjustNestedAnchors` to `loadDialog`, which I think is a more accurate description of its primary function.

Comment: This works great!  Thank you for pointing out my error and the function name suggestion!